# C# await client.GetAsync() failing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, amazon-web-services

I'm pulling data from Amazon via HTTP. The code works just fine in a small demo project, but in my main app it doesn't. When I call `FetchItem()` I receive this output:

```
'System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

After await `client.GetAsync()` the function returns and `url.Wait()` waits forever.

**Usage**

```
Task<string> url = FetchItem("ItemName", requestUrl);
url.Wait();
return url.Result;
```

**Source of FetchItem**

```
private static async Task<string> FetchItem(string sItemName, string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        XElement content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<XElement>();
        XNamespace ns = NAMESPACE;
        var isValidResults = content.Descendants(ns + "IsValid").AsParallel();

        foreach (var item in isValidResults)
        {
            if (item.Value != "True")
                return "Invalid Request";
        }
        var titleResults = content.Descendants(ns + sItemName).AsParallel();
        foreach (var item in titleResults)
        {
            if (item.Name == ns + sItemName)
                return item.Value; 
            // depending on the keyword, results can be quite fun.... :-)
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Caught Exception: " + e.Message);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: " + e.StackTrace);
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

Comment: Have closed as duplicate because all you are asking is: How to apply a timeout to a task?

Comment: You have edited the question so that now it is entirely different and no longer duplicate. I'll reopen.

Comment: Actually the problem isn't really related to `HttpClient`, but rather to how async methods work...

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're calling this code on the UI thread. What's happening is that `Wait`ing for the task to complete causes a deadlock. Your `FetchItem` method is asynchronous, and when you use `await` in it, the code that follows is transformed to a callback (called the continuation) that will be executed on the UI thread. But since the UI thread is busy waiting for the task to complete, it can't process the callback, so the task never completes. Hence the deadlock.

You should never `Wait` on the result of an async method. If you call an async method, use `await` to get its result. It means that the calling method also has to be async. Basically, when you start to use async in some part of the code, all the code that uses it needs to become async as well... (*)

---

(*) well, that's not exactly true. You can prevent the async method from resuming on the UI thread, by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the method you `await`. If you do that, the continuation will run on a thread pool thread, instead of the UI thread. This will also avoid the deadlock.

Comment: Yes, the original demo is a consol app and I added the `Wait()` in my Forms app. The consol app works fine. So a consol app is async and a forms app not? The better question may be: What is the best way to use async methods like `FetchItem()` in a Forms app?

Comment: @user3305711, it works in a console app, because console apps don't have a UI context, so continuations are always posted to the thread pool. As I said in my answer, the best way is to do async all the way; if an event handler calls async code, make it async as well.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `FetchItem()` to run sync. That did it for me:

```
private static string GetItem(string sItemName, string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        XElement content = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<XElement>().Result;
        ...
```

It doesn't make sense to me to rewrite half my app to go async.